# Which COM shim wizard version should I use with VS 2008 and Office 2003

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, excel-addins

On the download page for 2.3.1 it only mentions compatability with Office 2007.
I tried installing v2.0 but I couldn't see the wizards in the project types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508939.aspx) contain this phrase near the top:

> Applies to: 2007 Microsoft Office
>   System, Microsoft Office 2003,
>   Microsoft Office XP, Microsoft Office
>   2000

User comment in this employee [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/07/05/updated-com-shim-wizards.aspx):

> A small update : Just tried it on a PC
>   with Outlook 2003 and the addin works!

Good enough?

Comment: I tried it out with excel 2003 and it seems to work fine. I was thrown off my the fact that it only lists excel 97 on the download page for the shim wizard. I think the way that it works is that it detects what features you using by exaimining you addin, if you are building a 2003 add in it just won't find any 97 features.